# Destructuring in React props, don't understand {...{ [resourceName]: item }} inside props

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, destructuring

I came cross this code, and I don't understand `{...{ [resourceName]: item }}` inside the props inside the `RegularList.js` file.

I have two questions:

1. Whouldn't we, syntaxwise, write `sth.=sth`.
2. Which object is this `{...{ [resourceName]: item }}` trying to copy here?

Here's my code:

**RegularList.js**

```js
export const RegularList = ({
  items,
  resourceName,
  itemComponent: ItemComponent,
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      {items.map((item, i) => (
        <ItemComponent key={i} {...{ [resourceName]: item }} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

**App.js**

```js
const products = [{
    name: 'Flat-Screen TV',
    price: '$300',
    description: 'Huge LCD screen, a great deal',
    rating: 4.5,
}, {
    name: 'Basketball',
    price: '$10',
    description: 'Just like the pros use',
    rating: 3.8,
}, {
    name: 'Running Shoes',
    price: '$120',
    description: 'State-of-the-art technology for optimum running',
    rating: 4.2,
}];


    <RegularList
            items={products}
            resourceName="product"
            itemComponent={SmallProductListItem} />
```

**SmallProductListItem.js**

```js
export const SmallProductListItem = ({ product }) => {
    const { name, price } = product;

    return (
        <h3>{name} - {price}</h3>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
{ [resourceName]: item }
```

Is creating a new Object with a dynamic key `resourceName`

```js
...{}
```

Is spread operator.

So what is achieve here, is you pass a dynamic prop `resourceName` to your component.

For example, if `resourceName === "foo"` your `ItemComponent` will have the prop `foo`:

```
<ItemComponent foo={item} />
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. spread operator is to replicate sth right, why is it necessary here? why can't I just write an object directly here, sth of another form e.g. resourceName={item}, {[resourceName]=item} or {{[resourceName]= item }} (I know none of them worked...

Comment: You can pass props to a component using spred operator from an object. ie `const obj={prop1: value1, prop2: value}` => `<Component {...obj} />` is equivalent to `<Component prop1={value1} prop2={value2} />`. Having à dynamic prop (which is your case here) requires to use an object and spread it. Because you don't want props `resourceName` but the value of `resourceName` as propName (`foo` in my example)

Comment: I don't have 15 points to upvote...but Thanks a lot.